# Where to write code coverage data for scala rules?

Tags: bazel

This is a [repost from the bazel rules_scala issue tracker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/issues/184#issuecomment-304964598)

I'm working on adding support for `bazel coverage ...` for scala_libraries. I'm using [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin) scalac plugin to do the actual instrumentation and measurements but I'm having difficulty figuring out where to have the scalac plugin write coverage data to.

There seems to be a [COVERAGE_DIR env var](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/1fd27bc4d97533031401c54aa05eb75b13c6874b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/test/TestRunnerAction.java#L427-L435) set by the test runner by it doesn't seem to get set, though I've confirmed in my skylark rules that coverage is enabled.

I could use some direction on what I may be doing wrong

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on without more data (and ideally, a reproduction case). Most likely, your rules aren't reporting any covered files with instrumented_files (https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/rules.html#code-coverage-instrumentation). Bazel won't set COVERAGE_DIR if there are no instrumented files.